# Informatica Domain Configuration database connection during Powercenter installation

Tags: jdbc, installation, oracle-sqldeveloper, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to install Informatica Server. 
During domain configuration repository database information I get database connectivity error.

> Error: Test Connection Failed. Correct the database connection information and test the connection again.

[image]

But when I connect using same details through Oracle SQL Developer to this database, it works fine.

[image]

I am using service name and port number field from the TNS File, still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check tomcat log, catalina.out logs. This will help on finding out real issue. 
Go to command prompt and type ping localhost and see if its responding anything. May be you can use IP and check host file.